# Посоветуйте опенсорсный проект на C - образчик хорошего проектирования

Tags: c, модульность, проектирование, opensource

Моя проблема в том, что я, начиная с какого-то момента, начинаю закапываться в собственном коде. Отдельные части я пишу хорошо, а как надо свести их воедино - начинаю буксовать. Очень хотелось бы посмотреть, как профессионалы применяют модульное программирование в C.

Конечно, можно писать все функции так, чтобы их как можно проще было использовать "в вакууме". Собственно, так все стандартные функции и написаны (тот же strcmp, например). Но в реальном проекте очень часто это порождает функции с десятком параметров, да ещё и возвращающие несколько параметров, для чего надо городить какие-нибудь самодельные тьюплы.

Подозреваю, что я делаю что-то совсем не то и не так. Читал книги, которые учат писать продукты (а не куски кода), но там везде ООП. Книг по процедурному проектированию не нашёл.

Comment: http://www.gtk.org/

// Пишу комментарий, т.к. на ответ такой ссылки мало :)

Comment: https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3-BFG source 

http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3_bfg/index.php codereview

Comment: @VadimTukaev, а что вы имеете против ООП? ООП часто используется в проектах на C.

Comment: Посмотрите исходники git: https://github.com/git/git

Comment: @dzhioev, [200000](http://www.ohloh.net/p/git/analyses/latest/languages_summary) строк на Си за 8 лет. Не многовато для ознакомления?

@AlexDenisov, в GTK [полмиллиона строк](http://www.ohloh.net/p/gtk/analyses/latest/languages_summary), может сразу предложить почитать ядро Linux?

Comment: @avp, вы так говорите, как будто-бы это что-то плохое. 

Ядро Linux - это же очевидно, потому его советовать не стал.

Comment: @avp, ну автор и просил примеры большого и серьезного ПО, где используется модульная архитектура. 200000 строк - это среднего размера проект, да и не обязательно читать ВСЕ исходники, чтобы понять как он устроен.

Comment: @AlexDenisov, @dzhioev, вы сами-то считаете реальным понять (за разумное время) как написан проект из 100000++ строк?

Я так не считаю (поэтому ядро, gcc, python и т.п. не предлагал).

--

Пожалуй, можно предложить посмотреть законченную программу [netcat](http://code.ohloh.net/project?pid=7-T41uxAENE&prevcid=1&did=netcat&cid=MJaZv0DSJZA&fp=273012&projSelected=true) с [жалкими](http://www.ohloh.net/p/netcat/analyses/latest/languages_summary) 14433 строками кода (5675 на Си).

Comment: > автор и просил примеры большого и серьезного ПО

Как раз наоборот, проект желательно маленький, но сделанный очень хорошо и понятно, чтобы читать и наслаждаться, как хорошей книгой... Возможно, мне нужен развивающийся проект, который пока что мал, но изначально спроектирован "очень модульно", прям как конструктор Lego.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser

Возможно вам поможет эта ссылка. Думаю гугл все еще способен быть образцом.

Comment: Пожалуй это хороший вариант. Проект свежий, пока явно [небольшой](http://www.ohloh.net/p?q=gumbo) и похоже интересный.

Comment: Кажется, это то, что мне нужно. Эта функция меня сразу впечатлила:

    void* gumbo_parser_allocate(GumboParser* parser, size_t num_bytes) {
        return parser->_options->allocator(parser->_options->userdata, num_bytes);
    }

Плюс там свои вектора, свои строки... Многое можно позаимствовать. ;)